# Increase download speed of requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a script that download some videos from dropbox.  Usually my downloading speed is around 150 kb/sec, this when using normal downloader on firefox or IDM. But while using this Python script, things get too slow: less than 10 kb / sec.

Here's the code I'm using :

```
def download(url,i):
    local_filename = "video_" + str(i) + ".mp4"
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        n = 0
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1000000): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                n = n +1
                f.write(chunk)
                print "downloading " + str(n)
                f.flush() 
    return local_filename
```

Is there anyway I could speed up the download?

Comment: curious, how are you calculating download speed in your script?

Comment: Have you tried setting chunk_size to None instead of passing in a number. I believe this allows iter_content to determine the amount of content to load into memory before iterating on it.  It seems like you're loading a alot into memory before doing any work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that 1000000mb is to large of a value to load at one time.  You can't do anything with chunk while all that data is buffering into memory.  I would reduce the size to 512mb or 1gb if the file size is smaller than 512mb then the chunk size should be smaller than that, otherwise you're not really loading chunks, but the entire file...still if you search the net a bit you'll see that its a hot topic debate still. Example code:

```
def download(url,i):
    local_filename = "video_" + str(i) + ".mp4"
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f, closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as res:
        for n, chunk in enumerate(res.iter_content(chunk_size=512), start=1):
          f.write(chunk)
          print "downloading " + str(n)
    return local_filename
```

The [advance docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) suggest that when streaming to wrap it in the closing context. It should stabilize requests. The if chunk is not needed to filter out keep alive nor do you have to flush, just write to the file stream directly.

Comment: `with` statements support multiple contexts seperated by commas, so you could do `with open(...) as f, closing(...) as res:` instead of two nested with blocks.  Also if you are suggesting improvements you may consider using `enumerate` to handle the `n` value.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I did not realize that! Thanks for that!

Comment: You can add `start=1` to `enumerate` to make it begin counting at 1

Comment: Typically it goes after what you are iterating, but that works too :)

Comment: @cricket_007 lol sorry you're right, made the edit without really thinking.