# How can I exit a Python requests get when stream = True but data is not always flowing in?

Tags: python, python-requests, qthread

I am using requests to issue a get on a webpage where new data is added as events occur in the real world. I want to continue getting this data as long as the window is open so I set `stream = True` and then iterate line-by-line over the data as it streams in.

```
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
# Process the LiveLog data until stopped from exterior source
for html_line in page.iter_lines(chunk_size=1):
    # Do other work here
```

I have no problem with this part, but when it comes to exiting this loop I run into a problem. From looking at other StackOverflow threads I understand I can't catch any signals since my for loop is blocking. Instead I've tried using the following code which does work but with one big problem.

```
if QThread.currentThread().isInterruptionRequested():
    break
```

This code will get me out of my loop, but I've found that the only time the for loop iterates is when new data is introduced to the get, and in my situation this is not continuous. I could go without any new data for minutes or longer, and don't want to have to wait on this new data to land before I go through my loop again to check if an interruption is requested.

How can I exit my loop immediately after a user-action?

Comment: you can use `with`

Comment: Could you give some more detail? I'm not sure where I would use ```with``` to solve this problem.

Comment: you are lucky :P i were reading about the same today. here's it .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571466/increase-download-speed-of-requests

Comment: The linked content seems to do virtually the same thing as what I'm doing now. The ```with``` seems to be used as a method of cleaning up the get, but I don't think there's anything here about the problem of not being able to interrupt the ```for``` loop, especially if the data is not flowing continuously (making the for loop iterate continuously).

Comment: idk if `lock = threading.Lock()` can help you or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the aiohttp library https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp, and specifically https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streams.html#asynchronous-iteration-support. It would look something like:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def main():
    url = 'https://httpbin.org/stream/20'
    chunk_size = 1024
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            while True:
                data = await resp.content.readline():
                print(data) # do work here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

It's worth noting that `resp.content` is a `StreamReader` so you can use other methods available https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streams.html#aiohttp.StreamReader

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the original question "How can I exit my loop immediately after a user-action?". `asyncio.run(main())` blocks and will run forever. How can I tell it to stop running?